# Chef run sh script

Tags: shell, chef-infra, sh

I have a problem trying to run shell script via Chef (with docker-provisioning).

This is how I try to execute my script:

```
bash 'shell_try' do
   user "root"
   run = "#{some_path_to_script}/my_script.sh some_params"
   code " #{run} > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt"
end
```

(note that this script should run another scripts, processes and write logs)

Here's no errors in the output, but when I log into machine and run `ps aux` process isn't running.

I guess something wrong with permissions (or env variables), because when I try the same command manually - it works.

Comment: What happens when you move the ` run = "#{some_path_to_script}/my_script.sh some_params"` line outside of the `do` block?

Comment: Do you ever see stdout.txt or stderr.txt anywhere on the system? 

Hard to tell where they would be without absolute paths but my guess would be the file_cache_path or whatever chef's CWD is

Comment: @NilsLandt The run = "..." followed by code "#{run} ..." should work just fine, it's just a bit atypical and should probably be moved outside and before the `bash` resource call for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bash` resource just runs the provided script text directly, if you wanted to run a long-running process generally you would set up an Upstart or systemd service and use the `service` resource to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally find a solution (thanks to @coderanger) -

1. Install supervisor:

   - Download supervisor cookbook
   - Add: 
     include_recipe 'supervisor::default'
2. Add my service to supervisor:

   supervisor_service "name" do
     action :enable
     #action :start
     command '/path/script.sh start'

   end
3. Run supervisor service
4. All done!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Chef documentation for your resource: https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html. The `bash` resource does not support a `run` attribute. Text of the `code` attribute is run as a bash script. The default action is to `run` the script unless told otherwise by the resource.

```
bash 'shell_try' do
  user "root"
  code " #{run} > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt"
  action :run
end
```

The `code` attribute is written to a temporary file where it is then run using the attributes specified in the resource.

The line `run = "#{some_path_to_script}/my_script.sh some_params"` at this point does nothing.

Comment: The line run = "#{some_path_to_script}/my_script.sh some_params" it's just ruby variable, not an attribute.

Comment: It could be - 
`my_command = "#{some_path_to_script}/my_script.sh some_params"
code " #{my_command} > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt"`

Comment: I would argue that using the `code` attribute and `<<-EOH ... EOH` pattern would make it easier for the next guy to maintain. Put the entire script into a single location, whether a file or inline.